# How to replace a missing drawer in a built-in cabinet

Tags: replacement, drawers

Is there a simple kit or something to replace the drawer that my husband got rid of? I looked at some closet building materials but the drawer units were 24" wide -- too big. The opening is approx. 19"W x 4"H x 30"D. I'm no carpenter nor do I want a complicated project. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have pictures of an adjacent drawer? This would help us guide you.

Comment: There are companies which will sell you a drawer box built to your specified size. Installing the drawer on appropriate glides/guides, and staining/painting the false front (or fashioning your own  false front if it's not a very simple one) to match the appearance of the rest of the cabinet, is left to the buyer. Up to you to decide if that's simple enough; if it isn't you might want to hire someone or find a woodworking neighbor who is able to help you with this.

Comment: Do any of your other drawers fit the hole left by the missing one? If so, that'd give a cabinet maker all the info needed.